# How do I add cropperjs to my django project

Tags: javascript, django, cropperjs, cropper

I am working on a django project that requires adding a profile picture and that works; but where the problem comes in is that when someone uploads a picture that is quite long or quite wide, the profile image display would look weird. I tried initializing basic cropperjs by adding this to my `base.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css' %}">
<script type="module" src="{% static 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.js' %}">
```

and i just wanted to follow the docs and i kept my `edit-profile.html`

```
{% block content %}

<div class="image-box">
    <img src="{{ request.user.userprofile.profile_image.url }}" id="image" width="300px">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and my `edit-profile.js`

```
console.log('Hello there')

var $image = $('#image');

$image.cropper({
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    crop: function(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.x);
        console.log(event.detail.y);
        console.log(event.detail.width);
        console.log(event.detail.height);
        console.log(event.detail.rotate);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
    }
});

var cropper = $image.data('cropper');
```

but then when i `runserver` and i inspect the page, i see the error

```
edit_profile.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at edit_profile.js:3:14
```

so i tried creating a normal html file and linked it with a javascript file an then tried to initialize cropper. `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forum/static/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
    <title>Test site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="yor.png" id="image" width="300px">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="cropperjs/dist/cropper.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `main.js`

```
// import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';


const image = document.getElementById('image');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

and i get these set of errors

```
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/McDonald/Documents/Projects/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
index.html:17          GET file:///C:/Users/McDonald/Documents/Projects/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js net::ERR_FAILED
main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:2:1)
```

its getting quite confusing, and i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a common shortcut for [jQuery](https://jquery.com). You're using it on line 3 to select the element with the id of "image".

```js
var $image = $('#image');
```

Your (first) error is saying `$` is not defined, which means you didn't load jQuery. Make sure you load jQuery by including it using a script tag in your HTML somewhere.
Something like:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you should be able to run your first code with no problem!

Comment: Hopefully this solves your problem! If so, please accept the answer by checking the check mark! But if it doesn't and you're still having a cropperjs problem, [ask in a new separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I tried it but its still not working. it still gives me the error that "$" is not defined

Comment: Maybe you should wrap your entire edit-profile.js code in an onload event listener. `window.addEventListener("load", function (load) {  /* YOUR CODE */ })`. That way it won't try to use `$` until all JavaScript is loaded.